# What is the name of this kind of factoring algorithm

Tags: algorithms, factoring

I just think about algorithm to find factor of number by doing something like guessing last digit of number and increase digit bit by bit

Such as, I want to find factor of 749

Algorithm would begin guessing that only 3*3 and 7*7 can result in last digit 9

Then it would increase next digit. To find that only 83*03 and 07*07 result in last two digit 49 (43*43 also give 49 but it more than 749)

Then I would found only 107*007 is result factor of 749

Are there any name for this algorithm?

Comment: I'm afraid it is called "not better than trial division"

Comment: Base 2 is trivial in the sense that if last binary digit is zero (we call it bit), the number has at least one factor 2, and if it is composite with a trailing 1 bit, it has two odd factors. And your base 10 comment to @5xum does not explain how you factor 19*31.

Comment: @gammatester The thing is. trailing digit of number is also increased but still match with only some possible digit of factor. 19*31 is 589 and 89 is not 49 so it will excluded. same as 9*41 and 9*51 until 9*61 is 549. There are also 59*11 = 649. I need to keep all these factor pair and add more digit on each of them

Answer (score 0):

Your algirithm fails for a number like $19\cdot 31$, because it doesnt include the possibility that the last digit $9$ is obtained from $1\cdot 9$.

Even though the last digit is obtained from $m\cdot 1$, that doesn't mean that either of the factors will be equal to $1$. It just means one of the factors will **end** in a $1$.

Comment: Actually this algorithm would be on base 2 and it will reduced into 11*11 / 101*11 / 101 * 101 / 1001*11 or something like this which will just exclude 1 but include 49*101  and any other possibility. I just simplified it so I forgot 9 but concept is the same

Comment: @Thaina I don't see how the algorithm being in base 2 changes my argument...

Comment: Read it again that by being base 2 and increase digit by digit it would cope with 9 and your case is not a problem for me

Comment: OK Sorry, to put it simply. The algorithm in base 10 would not have 9*1 but would include 9*11 as another starter seed. But if in base 2 start with only 11*11 will cover all number so I just lazily skip it